# How to resignfirstResponser on x button action event in uisearch bar?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uisearchbar

[image]
I am unable to detect x button action in UISearchBar iOS 9. is there anyone can help me?

Comment: Where you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like,

```
func searchBar(searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
if searchText.characters.count == 0 {
    performSelector("hideKeyboardWithSearchBar:", withObject:searchBar, afterDelay:0)
}
}
```

refer [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UISearchBarDelegate/searchBar:textDidChange:) for more details

Hope this will help :)

```
func hideKeyboardWithSearchBar(bar:UISearchBar) {
bar.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: (x) button click event not detected

Comment: Have you set searchbar deleget to self ?

Comment: Mine is also not detecting x button click, and I have set delegate.

Answer (score 0):

if your view controller is your search bar delegate, you could implement `searchBarCancelButtonClicked` function and `resignFirstResponder` from there.

```
func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.text = ""
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    // or you could force view to end editing mode using self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: (x) button click event not detected